# Sorting uisng custom icons in custom data table component is not working in react

Tags: react-tsx, primereact

I created a custom data table component using primereact. I have two components which are holding Uparrow and DownArrow for sorting. They are not working as expected. Here is the code.

```
sortData = () => {
const { sortField, sortOrder } = this.props;
if (sortField) {
  // Create a sorted copy of the data based on the sortField and sortOrder.
  const sorted = [...this.props.data].sort((a, b) => {
    const aValue = a[sortField];
    const bValue = b[sortField];
    // Determine if the field values are numerical.
    const isNumerical = !isNaN(parseFloat(aValue)) && !isNaN(parseFloat(bValue));
    let result = 0;
    if (isNumerical) {
      // If the values are numerical, compare them directly.
      result = sortOrder === 1 ? aValue - bValue : bValue - aValue;
    } else {
      // If the values are not numerical, perform a string-based comparison.
      result = sortOrder === 1 ? aValue.localeCompare(bValue) : bValue.localeCompare(aValue);
    }
    return result;
  });
  // Update the dataToDisplay state with the sorted data.
  this.setState({ dataToDisplay: sorted });
}}
```

This is my sorting Logic and I am passing it in

```
handleSortClick = (field: string) => {
const { sortField, sortOrder } = this.state;

// Toggle the sortOrder if the same column is clicked again
const newSortOrder = field === sortField ? -sortOrder : 1;

// Update the state with the new sorting field and order
this.setState({
  sortField: field,
  sortOrder: newSortOrder,
});

// Trigger the onSortChange callback to sort the data externally
this.props.onSortChange(field, newSortOrder);}
```

and using in the components as click events.

```
<DataTable
        value={dataToDisplayPaginated}
        stripedRows
        scrollable
        className="custom-data-table-scroll"
      >
        {/* Check if the checkbox option is enabled and add checkbox column if true. */}
        {checkbox && (
          <Column
            key="checkbox"
            header={
              <Checkbox
                className="custom-checkbox"
                checked={selectAll}
                onChange={this.toggleAllRows}
              />
            }
            body={(rowData) => (
              <Checkbox
                className="custom-checkbox"
                checked={selectedRows.some((row) => row.id === rowData.id)}
                onChange={() => this.toggleRow(rowData)}
              />
            )}
          />
        )}
         {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child: ReactNode) => {
          if (React.isValidElement<ColumnProps>(child)) {
            const columnProps = child.props;
            const isSortable = columnProps.sortField === sortField;
            const upArrowClickHandler = () => {
              if (isSortable && columnProps.sortField) {
                this.handleSortClick(columnProps.sortField);
              }
            };
            const downArrowClickHandler = () => {
              if (isSortable && columnProps.sortField) {
                this.handleSortClick(columnProps.sortField);
              }
            };

            return React.cloneElement(child as React.ReactElement<ColumnProps>, {
              header: (
                <div className="column-header">
                  <span className="column-title">{this.getHeader(columnProps.header as string)}</span>
                  {isSortable && (
                    <div className="sorting-icons">
                      <button onClick={upArrowClickHandler}><UpArrow /></button>
                      <button onClick={downArrowClickHandler}><DownArrow /></button>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              ),
            });
          }
          return null;
        })}
      </DataTable>
```

Like this. I am able to click those buttons, but the sorting is not happening. Once it's done I want to pass the sortable property from data table to the component that I am using it as a boolean. I am using primereact column component for column. If I make the sortable to true I am getting the icons for sorting beside the column header from primereact. Instead of that I need to get these icons and able to sort.

please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are doing but here is a working reproducer showing you how to customize the Sort Icons properly: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h8t1sm?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying to pass my custom icons from my custom data table. So in the column component if sortable is true then I should see my custom Icons.